# Javascript: get the place of a string then generate random text

Tags: javascript

I have 3 example sentence here wherein names are dynamically generated.

Is it possible to get the place of this names, like getting that it is after the word "**I'm**" and before **,**

```
<p id="demo">Hi, I'm Johnny Bravo, how can i help you?</p>
```

or

```
<p id="demo">Hi, I'm Martir de Kuts, how can i help you?</p>
```

or

```
<p id="demo">Hi, I'm Jayson Dee, how can i help you?</p>
```

After getting the place of the name on the sentence. What I am going to do next is to generate a random name on it but i have a working code on it so i only need to determine is to get the place of the name based on my example.

****** **UPDATE to my POST** ******

This is what I am trying to achieve, now its working and thanks for helping me.

```js
var target = document.getElementById('demo');
var text = target.textContent;
var ArrayName = ['Vincent', 'Marie', 'Paul', 'Virginie'];
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * ArrayName.length); 
var randomElement = ArrayName[randomIndex];
var split1 = text.split(',');
var split2 = split1[1].split("I'm ")
split2[1] = randomElement;
split1[1] = split2.join("I'm ");
target.textContent = split1.join(',');
```

```html
<p id="demo">Hi, I'm Johnny Bravo, how can i help you?</p>
```

Comment: why do you need the place? ... you can just du a string replace and replace it!

Comment: yes you can find the the location of the name in the sentence but for that you need to know the name beforehand. and one more imp thing you can not have same id for different elements

Comment: never mind, didn't read the full question

Comment: @Manish - did you read my post? those elements are just an example!

Comment: @Felix i need the place of that word because i will be generating random text on that part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string split

```js
var target = document.getElementById('demo');
var text = target.textContent;
var split1 = text.split(',');
var split2 = split1[1].split("I'm ")
split2[1] = 'Foo Bar';
split1[1] = split2.join("I'm ");
target.textContent = split1.join(',');
```

```html
<p id="demo">Hi, I'm Johnny Bravo, how can i help you?</p>
```

Comment: thanks with this one. now i apply it to my codes and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_indexof.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Example:

```
var sentence = "Hi, I'm Johnny Bravo, how can i help you?";

var place = sentence.indexOf("Johnny Bravo");
//place = 9

sentence = sentece.replace("Johnny Bravo", "Gordon Freeman"); 
//sentence = "Hi, I'm Gordon Freeman, how can i help you?"
```

Comment: name is randomly generated based on my example